# Autocomplete is ignoring the minLength & delay setting

Tags: jquery, razor

I have the following script inside my razor view :-

```
$("#Technology2_Tag").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Switch/AutoComplete2",
            dataType: "json",
            minLength: 3, delay: 1000,
            data: {
                term: request.term,
                SearchBy: $("#ChoiceTag").prop("checked") ? $("#ChoiceTag").val() : $("#ChoiceName").val(),
            },
            success: function (data) {
                response(data);
            }
        });
    },
});
```

Currently the `autocomplete` is firing after typing the first character, instead of firing after typing at least 3 characters as mentioned in the `minLength` setting. Can anyone advise what might be the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Remove **,** on your `},` bracket

Comment: http://www.jqueryautocomplete.com/jquery-autocomplete-minlength.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are putting **autocomplete** properties in **ajax** properties, change it like this:

```
$("#Technology2_Tag").autocomplete({
             minLength: 3, 
             delay: 1000,
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Switch/AutoComplete2",
                    dataType: "json",

                    data: {
                        term: request.term,
                        SearchBy: $("#ChoiceTag").prop("checked") ? $("#ChoiceTag").val() : $("#ChoiceName").val(),
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            }

        });
```

Comment: it worked well, but interesting why i did not receive a error when i define the minlenghth inside the ajax setting ?

Comment: that's strange that it did'nt gave any error at runtime

Comment: Blaaaarrrh, I have looked at the "bug" for an hour now... and realized that I put both my delay and minLength inside the Ajax properties... and not those of autocomplete... *DOH* ! Thumbs up for this answer! Really helpfull

Answer (score 1):

I think the minLength and delay should be defined outside the definition of source :

```
$("#Technology2_Tag").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Switch/AutoComplete2",
                    dataType: "json",                       
                    data: {
                        term: request.term,
                        SearchBy: $("#ChoiceTag").prop("checked") ? $("#ChoiceTag").val() : $("#ChoiceName").val(),
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            },
             minLength: 3,
             delay: 1000,

        });
```